# Magento shopping cart rule, Can I create discount base on category and quantity?

Tags: magento, conditional-statements, categories, rule, discount

Magento shopping cart rule, Can I create discount base on category and quantity?

Ex. if buy products in a category more than 2 items, will get discount of the products.(not get discount all products in cart,  get discount for products in the category only)

Can I create condition same above on Magento shopping cart rule.

Comment: Very poor description of the problem. No effort shown. Provide detailed description of you problem. Add examples. Show us, what you already did on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it buy going to Admin->Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rules than click on Add New Rule and add the conditions and actions conditions as below.

Conditions:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
  If total quantity  equals or greater than  3  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
    Category  is  2 //change it as per your category
```

Action conditions:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Category  is  2  //change it as per your category
```